# Ansible- how I can pass in Jinja2 template all variables from block in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have simple Jinja2 template

```
[blockA]
{% include 'blockA.example.j2' %}
```

and blockA.example.j2 (this is not working)

```
{% for var in varBlockA %}
{{ var.% }}
{% endfor %}
```

and playbook have variables like this:

```
  vars:
    varBlockA:
      varA: value1
      varB: value2
```

and I searching correct Jinja2 format for blockA.example.j2. I need output like this

```
[blockA]
varA: value1
varB: value2
```

but I wan't definie varA,varB in Jinja2 because I wan't to limit myself due to the large number of parameters, the name and value of which I want to define from the playbook level, not the Jinja2 template.

Thanks.

Comment: this template file `blockA.example.j2` is in your current working directory? (current playbook directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different way to iterate over the `varBlockA` dictionary using `items()` function, so that you can access the key and value for each dictionary item.

`blockA.example.j2` for example:

```
{% for key, value in varBlockA.items() %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```